# ctypes find_library doesn't consult LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to use a `ctypes`-based wrapper for `librsync` on Linux which are installed in a non-standard path. However:

```
----> 1 import librsync
/home/ptest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/librsync/__init__.py in <module>()
     11     path = ctypes.util.find_library('rsync')
     12     if path is None:
---> 13         raise ImportError('Could not find librsync, make sure it is installed')
     14     try:
     15         _librsync = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(path)

ImportError: Could not find librsync, make sure it is installed
```

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has been set prior, but `ctypes` doesn't seems to honor it. The search suggested many questions asked along this line, but I can't seem to find a solution. Any help?

Comment: The docs tell you that the "purpose of the `find_library()` function is to locate a library in a way similar to what the *compiler* does" (my emphasis). gcc uses `LIBRARY_PATH`. The runtime linker, `ld.so`, uses `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You'd have to set both environment variables for `ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library('rsync'))` to work in general. You can set `LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime, e.g. `os.environ['LIBRARY_PATH'] = os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']`.

Comment: that is it, I totally missed the difference. Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Python 3.6, [it does](https://bugs.python.org/issue9998).

For earlier versions, [@eryksun suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309693/ctypes-find-library-doesnt-consult-ld-library-path#comment52495164_32309693) this workaround:

```
os.environ['LIBRARY_PATH'] = os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']
```

Answer (score -2):

do this before:

```
sudo apt-get install librsync-dev
```