# Why can't this library load using ctypes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

On linux, I am unable to get find_library to return the found library name. The full file name is `libmystuff.so` and it sits in the dir `/opt/myapp/mylibs`. The docs describe it's naming as follows.

> Try to find a library and return a pathname. name is the library name without any prefix like lib, suffix like .so, .dylib or version number (this is the form used for the posix linker option -l). If no library can be found, returns None.

I try and use it like the following, but libname is always 'None'.

```
import ctypes
import os

from ctypes.util import find_library

os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/opt/myapp/mylibs'

libname = find_library("mystuff")
```

I also have tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my shell env.

Comment: Ummm, the question may be a bit misleading, not sure if I should change it, but the issues is that "I am unable to get find_library to return the found library name."

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for the old python version](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#finding-shared-libraries) you're using say:

> The purpose of the find_library() function is to locate a library **in a way similar to what the compiler does**. [...] On Linux, find_library() tries to run external programs (/sbin/ldconfig, gcc, and objdump) to find the library file.

It doesn't attempt to load the library, and it [doesn't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in versions earlier than Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32309693/1026).

Note the other suggestion from the docs:

> If wrapping a shared library with ctypes, it may be better to determine the shared library name at development time, and hardcode that into the wrapper module instead of using find_library() to locate the library at runtime.